# Access iPhone disk from iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

We have a scenario to access the iphone disk space like the following,

1 . user will put a file in the disk space and runs the app
2. The app will have to access the disk space and identify the file posted by the user.
3. i might pull the file into the app and parse and do the business logic.

is it possible by any chance, i see it as impossible legally now.

Kindly help

PS: The app will go to apple for verification process and will be available in app store.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the user is willing to use iTunes to copy the file to the device, this is perfectly possible in 3.2/4.0. See `UIFileSharingEnabled` in the documentation.

Comment: Hi Ole Begemann: Thanks for the response firstly.
How will i be able to upload files into the device from iTunes? can the file be in .xml (for that matter any other file formats) format? Kindly advise

Comment: As I said, read the documentation. Then come back with specific questions.